# How to delete contact number permantely from contact list?

Tags: android, cursor

I want to delete contact permanently from my contact list.
I am using following code.

```
public boolean deleteContact(String phone, String name) {
    System.out.println("name :: "+name +"  "+phone);
    Uri contactUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI,
            Uri.encode(phone));
    Cursor cur = context.getContentResolver().query(contactUri, null, null,
            null, null);
    try {
        if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                if (cur.getString(
                        cur.getColumnIndex(PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME))
                        .equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
                    String lookupKey = cur
                            .getString(cur
                                    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY));
                    Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(
                            ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_LOOKUP_URI,
                            lookupKey);
                    int i = context.getContentResolver().delete(uri, null, null);
                    System.out.println("i :::: "+i);
                    return true;
                }

            } while (cur.moveToNext());
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getStackTrace());
    }
    return false;
}
```

In my mobile contact I have a contact named "SIRI" with two mobile numbers. The above code deletes both numbers. I want to remove only selected number not both numbers.

Answer (score 0):

If you only one want to delete the selected phone number, try this:

```
Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(phone));
resolver.delete(uri, null, null);
```

Simpler to do all in one go:

```
Uri uri = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;

String selections =  ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER + " = ' + phone + ' AND " +  ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME.toLowerCase() + " = ' + name.toLowerCase() + '";

int res = contentResolver.delete(uri, selections, null);
```

Comment: If that name having two numbers means i want to delete selected number not name and other number also. Thank you for reply.